# JQuery calendar not working after ajax call, but the button is there?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, datepicker

i'm having an issue here with JQuery calendar, it doesn't work after an ajax call. I've tried a lot of options, but any of them worked

this is my js:

```
function carregar(metodo, div) {
    var loading = new Image();
    loading.src = "${resource(dir: 'images', file: spinner.gif)}";
    $.ajax({
        url: metodo,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'text',
        beforeSend: function () {
            $("#" + div).html(loading);
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $("#" + div).html(data);

        }
    });
}

$(function () {
    $("#nascimento").datepicker({
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/images/calendar.gif",
        buttonImageOnly: true
    });
});
```

this is the index, where I call the ajax function:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>
<html>
    <head> 
        <meta name="layout" content="main" />
        <title>Cadastrar Aluno</title>
    </head>
    <body>                
        <input type="button" value="Novo"  onClick="carregar('/aluno/novo', 'divForm')"/> 
        <input type="button" value="Pesquisar"  onClick="carregar('/aluno/pesquisar', 'divForm')"/> 


    <div id="divForm">        
        <g:render template="form"></g:render>
        </div>       
    </body>
</html>
```

And this is my form template:

```
<asset:javascript src="application.js"/> 
<g:uploadForm controller="aluno" action="salvar">    
    //other fields
    <label>Data de Nascimento:</label>    
    <input type="text" name="nascimento" id="nascimento" required="true" value="<g:formatDate format="dd-MM-yyyy" date="${aluno?.nascimento}"/>"/><br>           
    //other fields
    <input type="submit" value="Salvar"/>
    <input type="button" name="btnCancelar" value="Cancelar"/> 
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="${aluno?.id}">    
</g:uploadForm>
```

If I put

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $( "#nascimento" ).datepicker();
    });
</script>
```

in the template, ir works one time, If I load the "form" template again after reloading the page, it doesn't.

I've tried this:
[jquery datepicker doesn't work after ajax call if its already on page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27577558/jquery-datepicker-doesnt-work-after-ajax-call-if-its-already-on-page)
[JQuery datepicker not working after ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20453879/jquery-datepicker-not-working-after-ajax-call)
[jQuery datepicker does not work after Ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14087501/jquery-datepicker-does-not-work-after-ajax-call)

do you guys have any ideas?

thanks!

Comment: Is the calendar element inside the html that you are replacing?

Comment: yes, and that is the problem. <input type="text" name="nascimento" id="nascimento" required="true" value="<g:formatDate format="dd-MM-yyyy" date="${aluno?.nascimento}"/>"/><br> is it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you reload your html, you are destroying the element that had the datepicker attached to it and recreating it anew.

As such, you'll need to re-initialize the datepicker after you replace the html, with something like this:

```
                 success: function (data) {
                    $("#" + div).html(data);
                    $("#nascimento").datepicker('remove').datepicker({
                        showOn: "button",
                        buttonImage: "http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/images/calendar.gif",
                        buttonImageOnly: true
                    });

                }
```

Comment: Already tried that, it still doesn't work... weird stuff is that even if I don't put this, the button/image is there, but doesn't work when I click it

Comment: Is this on a page somewhere where we can see it?

Comment: Yes the input and the button/image are there, even a mask plugin that I'm using is working, just the calendar isn't shown when I click it

Comment: No, I mean, can you provide a link to a page so we can go there and see it happen?

Comment: sadly not yet, do you know any easy way to do it so you can see it?

Comment: Not really, hosting it on a server is about the only way, But see my update which adds `.datepicker('remove')` before the init. I think it still thinks the element still has a datepicker attached. Does that work now?

Comment: No.. but when I removed <asset:javascript src="application.js"/>  from the template, it started to work properly, apparently it was a problem with importing this javascript file twice, my fieldmasks was working weird too; Thanks!